# If $X_n \sim Geo(p_n)$ then $X_n \overset{D}{\rightarrow} X$, where $X \sim Geo(p)$

Tags: probability-theory

I want to show that if$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} p_n = p$ and we have $X_n \sim Geo(p_n)$  then $\forall n, X_n \overset{D}{\rightarrow} X$, where $X \sim Geo(p)$.

I know that there is a theorem that states that if $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} E[f(X_n] = E[f(x)]$ for every continuous function $f$ then $X_n \overset{D}{\rightarrow} X$, but it is not very clear to me how to properly apply the theorem here. Any suggestions on how to prove the convergence in distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition and observe that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n\leq k)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^k(1-p_n)^jp_n=\sum_{j=0}^k(1-p)^jp=\mathbb{P}(X\leq k).$$

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting question is whether the convergence is uniform in $n$

Comment: Okay, I know that $p_n \to p$, but why is it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^k(1-p_n)^jp_n=\sum_{j=0}^k(1-p)^jp?$ The part that is not that clear to me is the term involving $(1-p_n)^j$

Comment: @RahidFayad if $f$ is a continuous function and $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a convergent sequence, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\right).$$ So note that $f(x)=(1-x)^j$ defines a continuous function

Comment: Oh that's right, it was easier than I thought. Thanks for your help!